# Adding remote machine to AD via Powershell

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, powershell

So I have a powershell script, `Add-Computer -ComputerName $computername  -LocalCredential $computername\admin -DomainName $domain -Credential domain\$username -Force -Restart`

So if I have a machine that has either fallen off the domain or is disabled, and I run the following command, I get an error: `Remove-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer '$computername' with the following error message: The 
RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).`

Now I have verified that the machine is in fact on the network and I am able to RDP to it. IS there something wrong or will this not work if the machine is not active in AD?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Firewall on the machine in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, if I `set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value *` on my local machine to allow remote connections from untrusted sources since certificate errors don't pop up.

And then move it into a `ScriptBlock` it runs.

Comment: Glad you've resolved this. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're able.

Answer (score 1):

Add-Computer will add the local computer to a domain : [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849798%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)

You can try to add your machine using [PowerShell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your machine is online make sure *Remote Registry* service is running and accessible, ie. disable firewall or create an exception.

Comment: `make sure Remote Registry service is running and accessible, ie. disable firewall or create an exception` - Creating a firewall rule for the Remote Registry service doesn't start the service. The OP needs to do both, create a firewall rule and start the service.

Comment: @joeqwerty - that's what the answer says _""..make sure Remote Registry service is running **and** accessible.."_ where **and** implies what it traditionally does which is both conditions to be true:)

Comment: I took your use of ie to mean `in essence` which I thought meant that you were implying that creating a firewall rule was all that was necessary and I wanted to clarify that the service needs to be started `in addition to` creating a firewall rule.

Comment: *i.e.* is actually an abbreviation for the Latin *id est*.  Although "in essence" isn't a bad translation of the meaning.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(I)  I must admit to making the same mistake myself once.